# get the menu items for Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, menu, woocommerce, categories

I used the following code to get the product categories from woocommerce.

```
<?php  
 $args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'product',  
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
     'product_cat' => 'blazzers , Hoodies & Pullovers, jackets',
    'orderby' => 'ASC' 
    );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product;
 ?>
```

I want to get the product categories from a menu like "tops".
In the code above I try to add inside the array:

```
'menu' => 'tops',
```

But I didn't have any results. Any feedback?

Answer (score 0):

For menu items you can use the **wp_get_nav_menu_items** function.

Here are the parameters which you can pass according to your requirement.

[image]

Also, here I have shared the link for better understanding.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_nav_menu_items/